# What are apvectors and apstrings in C++?

Tags: c++

I am learning C++ with the book "*How to think like a computer scientist, C++ edition*" and I have come across **apvectors** and **apstrings**.

The book doesn't explain what they are, and after searching on-line, I am none the wiser. Could someone explain them please?

Comment: I'm guessing they're the classes used for AP Computer Science exams, created by those people.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at the **Appendix A**, they are defined in that section.

```
A Quick reference for AP classes 175
A.1 apstring . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 175
A.2 apvector . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 176
A.3 apmatrix . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . . 177
```

They are just a stripped down version of `std` counterparts. Perhaps meant for teaching purposes considering the scope of this book.

Answer (score 0):

They appear to be classes and class templates defined by and for use with the [College Board Advanced Placement (AP) Computer Science](https://apstudent.collegeboard.org/apcourse/ap-computer-science-a) course:

From Appendix A in http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkcpp/thinkCScpp.pdf:

> ### Quick reference for AP classes
>
> These class definitions are copied from the College Board web page,
>   http://www.collegeboard.org/ap/computer-science/html/quick_ref.htm
>   with minor formatting changes. [...]

From a quick look at the interfaces, you should be able to replace `apstring` and `apvector` with `std::string` and `std::vector` without any other changes required.